# Can a client find out which region an AWS-hosted webapp is in?

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, ip

As indicated in the title, I want to know if it is possible to know the region of a given AWS service, for examlple using ip address or traceroute tool.

Thank in advance.

Comment: What service? And how are they accessing it? It's possible with certain services, but not others

Comment: web applicant behind a load balancer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes indeed once the IP address is known it can be matched against the publically available IP Address table from AWS.

The IP Address range is always found here https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json